# Is this a time-travel discrepancy in Gone World?

Tags: time-travel, plot-device, timeline, the-gone-world

This is a question on [Gone World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33413556-the-gone-world).

At one point, Shannon gets back in time without the formal channel (i.e. getting on her ship and heading back over a period of 3 months). She actually uses the time-space anomaly created by the Libra to get back to her time. Once she gets back, she is found by her team and is treated for her wounds.

My question:
Since she didn't use the designated way to get back in time, her time, shouldn't there have been two Shannons when she got back? She did slip through the space-time to get back to the 90s meaning, she slipped into a timeline that is not hers. There should have been another Shannon living in that timeline. No?